# Are there any alternatives to py2exe?

Tags: python, py2exe

Are there any alternatives to py2exe?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) is cross-platform and does the same, or you could use [py2app](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/), which works on mac only.

Comment: works great, but how can i set an icon for my exe?

Comment: You could take a look at the icon option in the setup script.

Answer (score 60):

[pyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) is cross-platform and very powerful, with many third-party packages (matplotlib, numpy, PyQT4, ...) specially supported "out of the box", support for eggs, code-signing on Windows (and a couple other Windows-only goodies, optional binary packing... the works!-)  The one big issue: the last "released" version, 1.3, is ages-old -- you absolutely must install the SVN trunk version, `svn co http://svn.pyinstaller.org/trunk pyinstaller` (or the 1.4 pre-release, but I haven't tested that one).  A fair summary of its capabilities as of 6 months ago is [here](http://www.pycon.it/media/stuff/slides/distribuire-programmi-python-con-pyinstaller.pdf) (in English, despite the Italian URL;-).

Comment: pyInstaller looked like the most robust of those I tried recently (pyInstaller, cx_Freeze, bbfreeze). Additionally to what Alex mentioned, offers a "no-console" option for Windows, correctly includes the modules, well-documented, is installed separately from the Python installation so you can switch between versions if need be.

Comment: unfortunately no python3 support yet. the one python app i want to generate an exe for i happened to write in python3.1 :P

Comment: PyInstaller rocks! I only had one little issue with ctypes since it couldn't find the referenced DLL, but after manually copying it to the output folder everything worked perfectly!

Comment: Note: PyInstaller has been moved to GitHub. See: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller

Comment: pyinstaller works well but sadly seems to have issues with many anti-virus vendors. Although I have not had issues with false positives, it seems to take an age to scan the .exe when it starts, and I cannot possibly test for all the various AV packages out there. For code you intend to release in the wild, this kind of problem could become very painful. (I am using 3.5)

Answer (score 20):

[Here's a list of them.](http://www.freehackers.org/Packaging_a_python_program)

1. Py2exe
2. PyInstaller
3. cx_Freeze
4. bbfreeze
5. py2app

You might also consider [Nuitka](https://nuitka.net/pages/overview.html), which compiles python to native code.

Answer (score 6):

[bbfreeze](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bbfreeze/) claims to works on Windows and UNIX, but not on OS X.  It doesn't seem to be actively developed anymore, though.

Comment: `bfreeze` and the programs it creates are unfortunately detected as malicious by anti-virus software (Norton in particular). It is a problem for users since you can hardly tell them to turn off such and such feature of their system protection. For the record, I personally hate those experimental anti-virus detection features.

Comment: bbfreeze appears to have support for OSX on its trunk ("tip") version, though not in a released version.  And I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: According to virustotal.com the executable that bbfreeze created for me is not being picked up by Norton as a virus. (Of course it could still be detected during runtime due to some "Behavioral Protection" magic.)

Comment: bbfreeze worked for me where pyinstaller failed, see https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2009 for details