# Python py2exe - memory load error

Tags: python, py2exe

I am creating a medium level application in Python.
Everything works well now, and I am trying to make this a windows executable with py2exe.
The executable is created fine, but when I try to run it, it fails with the following error.

```
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "ffhandler.pyo", line 33, in ?
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "pyAA\__init__.pyo", line 1, in ?
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "pyAA\AA.pyo", line 8, in ?
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "pyAA\pyAAc.pyo", line 5, in ?
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 98, in load_module
ImportError: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading pyAA\_pyAAc.pyd
```

I am using pyAA in this application. I searched internet, but was unable to get any solution.
I copied msvcp71.dll to windows/system32, but still issue is there.

I had solved it earlier (around 7 months back), but my hard drive crashed and when I try to recreate it, I cannot seem to solve it now. :-(

I would be much obliged if someone could help me out here.

EDIT:
When I use py2exe without bundle files option, it is working perfectly. But when I use bundle file option, it is failing.

I tried without zipfile option, wherein it creates a library.zip alongwith the executable. Again it failed. I did unzip of library.zip using 7-zip, and found that _pyAAc.pyd is there in pyAA folder inside the zip file. So, it looks like some issue with memoryloadlibrary function.

When I tried to unzip using windows unzip function, it failed. I had to use 7-zip to unzip it. Is it a possible clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing some DLL's in your build...

First search your hard drive for the file `_pyAAC.pyd`. Make sure it is included (shipped) in your build.

Then use ['dependency walker'](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on the .pyd file (in your py2exe compiled version!) to see what it is that is still missing (other DLL's which are causing the `MemoryLoadLibrary` message for the .pyd file). Make sure these dependencies are also shipped, ...

Comment: Thank you ChristopheD. I checked it, but found that it is indeed shipped. I have made some modifications in my question, please see the same.

Comment: I've seen this before in the past (some dll's don't like to be shipped with the bundle_files option set. Don't really know a way around it. A way could be to build with bundle_files off. Or you could have a look at alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689086/are-there-any-alternatives-to-py2exe (e.g. pyinstaller)