# How to convert a .pyc to a .exe file

Tags: python, executable, py2exe

I want to create the Windows executable file of my project, but I don't want to share the source code.
I use Linux, but py2exe doesn't work on Linux. Is there a py2exe alternative for Linux?

Comment: py2exe doesn't really hide your source code

Comment: You can't hide your source code. If someone really wants to decompile your program, they'll do it. And Python is *much* easier to decompile than C++ and C, as it's "binaries" are pretty descriptive, so there's really no use in trying to hide the source. Py2exe just packages the generated binaries, so if I can extract your `exe` file, I can decompile your program with ease.

Comment: @Blender how to hide the sourse code or how to make the trial version of my software . can you provide me the link to any website or book from where i read the complete software development process

Comment: You can't. Read this question for more details as to why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code

Comment: If that's the question, there are countless duplicates (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code being the most popular canidate) - so, is that the case?

Comment: It's a mix of that and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709925/how-to-make-an-executable-file-in-python. I'm not sure if you can call it a duplicate, but I'll flag it.

Comment: thanks blender this help alot

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use [`cx_freeze`](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/).

I've tried `py2exe`, and it doesn't handle dependencies as well as `cx_freeze`. Best of all, it's cross-platform! I've made Windows and Linux binaries with it, so I can confirm it works properly.

Here's a little tutorial to get you started: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/08/12/a-cx_freeze-tutorial-build-a-binary-series/.

Comment: Your `cx_freeze` link is broken

Answer (score 1):

Checkout http://www.py2exe.org/

Also look at this question: [How to make an executable file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709925/how-to-make-an-executable-file-in-python)