# Micropython or minimal python installation

Tags: python

I once read about minimal python installation without a lot of the libraries that come with the python default installation but could not find it on the web...

What I want to do is to just pack a script with the python stuff required to execute it and make portable.

Does any one know about something like that?

Thanks

Comment: most programs used to generate an executable from your python code allow you to choose to remove unwanted libraries, is that what you are talking about?

Comment: See also the answers to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689086/are-there-any-alternatives-to-py2exe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Micro Python](https://micropython.org/) is actively maintained and has been ported to a bunch of microcontrollers.

For other small implementations, you might also want to check out [tinypy](http://www.tinypy.org/) or [PyMite](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyMite).

If you don't care about size, but really just want an easy way to distribute a python program, consider [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) or one of the others on [this list](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DistributionUtilities).

Comment: Have you used tinypy? How is it?

Answer (score 2):

[Portable python](http://www.portablepython.com/) might do what you want. It's a python installation for USB thumb drives.

Comment: Python 2.7 download amounts 240 MB. I am not going to check out Python 3.2. I'll wait for more minimal or portable release.

Comment: Portable Python is not being developed anymore.  @forest's answers (tinpy, micro python, pymite) are still-active alternatives.

Comment: new Python 2.7-3.8 (35 MB) https://sourceforge.net/projects/portable-python/files/

Answer (score 2):

There's now finally Micro Python, claiming to be full reimplementation of Python 3 core, fitting even into medium-size 32bit microcontrollers. API will be different of course, so C modules will require porting. Project is funded via KickStarter, source code will be released some time after the campaign (request for consideration was made to author to not delay release of the source, to help bootstrap Micro Python community sooner).

http://micropython.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can also look for already installed instances.

**OpenOffice / LibreOffice**

Look at the environment variable UNO_PATH or into the default install directories, for example for Windows and LO5

> %ProgramFiles(x86)%\LibreOffice 5\program\python.exe

**Gimp**

look into the default install directories, for example for Windows

> C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\Python

and so on...

Comment: or standalone python.exe (10Mb) in https://sourceforge.net/projects/calculixforwin/files/03.4/