# cross-compiling Python 2.7.4+

Tags: python, python-2.7, cross-compiling

There are several tutorials on the web documenting how to cross-compile or cross-build Python for various embedded systems using some basic hacking and patching, like so:

http://randomsplat.com/id5-cross-compiling-python-for-embedded-linux.html

This worked well for me in the past, when I was using Python 2.7.2.

In Python 2.7.4, some cross-compile functionality was finally included in the upstream build process, documented here:

- http://bugs.python.org/issue17086
- https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2013-February/123779.html

This breaks all of the previous cross-build hacks, and I cannot find any updated tutorials or documentation for the new built-in cross-compile procedure.

Does anyone have a good example or documentation on using the new cross-compile procedure for Python 2.7.4 and onward in the 2.7 branch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After diving into the existing patches and changes, I was able to produce a modified patch set that utilizes the latest cross-compiling features for 2.7.5.

http://www.trevorbowen.com/2013/10/07/cross-compiling-python-2-7-5-for-embedded-linux/

Paul also references it on his original "classic" cross-compile-Python post:

http://randomsplat.com/id5-cross-compiling-python-for-embedded-linux.html

HTH

Comment: In your example you move aside python and pgen (X_for_build) but you do not reference them on the cross config/build (while the other, "Paul" link does)

Answer (score 1):

For posterity...

Though the question is specifically about Python 2.7, if you're willing to step up to Python3, another option for embedded/micro with good cross-compiling features/support is [Micro Python](http://micropython.org); (see also [June 2014 announcement](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2014-June/672994.html) though it was around before that).

See also [this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035572/micropython-or-minimal-python-installation) about small/portable (in multiple senses) Python implementations.