# What files are required for Py_Initialize to run?

Tags: python, c++, ctypes, embedding

I am working on a simple piece of code that runs a Python function from a C/C++ application. In order to do this I set the PYTHONPATH and run initialize as follows:

```c++
Py_SetPythonHome("../Python27");
Py_InitializeEx(0);
```

Then I import my module and run my function. It works great.

I am now attempting to build an installer for my colleagues to run my code. I want to minimize the number of files I need to include in this installer, for obvious reasons.

Googling around the subject tells me that I should be able to include the files "Python27.lib" and "Python27.dll", then zip the "DLLs" and "Lib" folders and include them. However, when I attempt this, Py_Initialize fails.

A quick examination of what is causing this failure shows that Py_Initialize appears to depend upon a number of .pyc files in the Lib folder including (but not limited to *warnings.pyc*, *_abcoll.pyc*, *_future_.pyc* and the contents of the "encodings" folder.

I cannot understand why this would be. Any advice?

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035572/micropython-or-minimal-python-installation

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39539089/what-files-are-required-for-py-initialize-to-run/39541474#39541474) helpful?

Comment: Thanks Cristi. Was unable to test your solution over the weekend. I am testing it now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the beginning, I wanted to say that there's no module required (at least no *non-builtin* one) for *Py_InitializeEx*, so the only requirement was *python27.dll* (*BTW*: *python27.lib* is **not** required, unless your colleagues want to link something against it - but that wouldn't be very easy *w / o* *Python*'s *Include* *dir*). 
I had this code (using *Python 2.7.10* that I built using *VStudio **10*** (*2010*)):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Python.h>


int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char *pyCode = 
        "s = \"abc\"\n"
        "print s, 1234";
    Py_InitializeEx(0);
    i = PyRun_SimpleString(pyCode);
    Py_Finalize();
    printf("PyRun_SimpleString returned: %d\nPress a key to exit...\n", i);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

It built fine, it ran *OK* from *VStudio*, and from the command line (after copying the *.dll* in its folder). But then I copied the *.exe* and *.dll* to another computer and when running, ***bang!!!***

> ```
> ImportError: No module named site
> ```

Considering that:

- I have no *PYTHON** *env vars* set in neither of the consoles on the 2 machines where I ran the *.exe* (with different results)
- On both machines the *Python* installation is on the same path (I previously (years ago) modified it on the machine that doesn't work)

I don't know why it doesn't behave the same (one thing that I haven't check is that there might be some registry key on the machine that works?).

**Note**: ***site*** is a (*.py(c)*) module located under ***%PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\Lib***.

Then, I browsed *Python*'s source code and I came across [[GitHub]:  python/cpython - (v2.7.10) cpython/Python/pythonrun.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/pythonrun.c) (function ***Py_InitializeEx*** - currently line ***#141***) - this is how I'm going to refer a point in the source code):

```
if (!Py_NoSiteFlag)
    initsite(); /* Module site */
```

while in ***initsite***:

```
m = PyImport_ImportModule("site");
```

which is pretty obvious (*Py_NoSiteFlag* is ***0***).

Then I noticed that *Py_NoSiteFlag* is declared as `extern __declspec(dllexport)` ([[MS.Learn]: Using extern to Specify Linkage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/0603949d(v=vs.100)), [[MS.Learn]: dllexport, dllimport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/3y1sfaz2(v=vs.100))), so I modified my code to:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Python.h>

extern __declspec(dllimport) int Py_NoSiteFlag;


int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char *pyCode = 
        "s = \"abc\"\n"
        "print s, 1234";
    Py_NoSiteFlag = 1;
    Py_InitializeEx(0);
    i = PyRun_SimpleString(pyCode);
    Py_Finalize();
    printf("PyRun_SimpleString returned: %d\nPress a key to exit...\n", i);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

and it works! **Yay!**

So, at this point only the *.dll* is required in order to run a piece of code. But I imagine that your code is "a little bit" more complex than that (it has ***import***s ([[Python 2.Docs]: The import statement](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/import.html)). To solve the *import* problem, you can use this nice module: [[Python 2.Docs]:  modulefinder - Find modules used by a script](https://docs.python.org/2/library/modulefinder.html?highlight=modulefinder#module-modulefinder) (part of *Python 2.7*'s standard modules). To make use of it:

- Save the code that you execute from *C* in a *.py* file
- Run *modulefinder* against it

Here's an example for my code (*pyCode* contents in my *C* program, saved in a file).

*code00.py*:

```py
s = "abc"
print(s, 1234)
```

Running:

> ```bat
> ${PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR}\python.exe -m modulefinder code00.py
> ```

yields:

> ```
> Name                      File
> ----                      ----
> m __main__                code00.py
> ```

**But**, if I add an `import os` (which is a pretty common module) statement in the file, the above command yields:

> ```
> Name                        File
> ----                        ----
> m StringIO                  %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\StringIO.py
> m UserDict                  %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\UserDict.py
> m __builtin__
> m __future__                %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\__future__.py
> m __main__                  a.py
> m _abcoll                   %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\_abcoll.py
> m _codecs
> m _collections
> m _functools
> m _hashlib                  %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
> m _heapq
> m _io
> m _locale
> m _random
> m _sre
> m _struct
> m _subprocess
> m _threading_local          %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\_threading_local.py
> m _warnings
> m _weakref
> m _weakrefset               %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\_weakrefset.py
> m abc                       %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\abc.py
> m array
> m atexit                    %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\atexit.py
> m bdb                       %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\bdb.py
> m binascii
> m cPickle
> m cStringIO
> m cmd                       %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\cmd.py
> m codecs                    %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\codecs.py
> m collections               %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\collections.py
> m copy                      %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\copy.py
> m copy_reg                  %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\copy_reg.py
> m difflib                   %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\difflib.py
> m dis                       %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\dis.py
> m doctest                   %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\doctest.py
> m dummy_thread              %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\dummy_thread.py
> P encodings                 %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\encodings\__init__.py
> m encodings.aliases         %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\encodings\aliases.py
> m errno
> m exceptions
> m fnmatch                   %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\fnmatch.py
> m functools                 %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\functools.py
> m gc
> m genericpath               %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\genericpath.py
> m getopt                    %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\getopt.py
> m gettext                   %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\gettext.py
> m hashlib                   %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\hashlib.py
> m heapq                     %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\heapq.py
> m imp
> m inspect                   %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\inspect.py
> m io                        %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\io.py
> m itertools
> m keyword                   %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\keyword.py
> m linecache                 %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\linecache.py
> m locale                    %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\locale.py
> P logging                   %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\logging\__init__.py
> m marshal
> m math
> m msvcrt
> m nt
> m ntpath                    %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\ntpath.py
> m opcode                    %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\opcode.py
> m operator
> m optparse                  %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\optparse.py
> m os                        %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\os.py
> m os2emxpath                %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\os2emxpath.py
> m pdb                       %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\pdb.py
> m pickle                    %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\pickle.py
> m posixpath                 %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\posixpath.py
> m pprint                    %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\pprint.py
> m random                    %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\random.py
> m re                        %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\re.py
> m repr                      %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\repr.py
> m select                    %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\DLLs\select.pyd
> m shlex                     %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\shlex.py
> m signal
> m sre_compile               %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\sre_compile.py
> m sre_constants             %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\sre_constants.py
> m sre_parse                 %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\sre_parse.py
> m stat                      %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\stat.py
> m string                    %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\string.py
> m strop
> m struct                    %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\struct.py
> m subprocess                %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\subprocess.py
> m sys
> m tempfile                  %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\tempfile.py
> m textwrap                  %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\textwrap.py
> m thread
> m threading                 %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\threading.py
> m time
> m token                     %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\token.py
> m tokenize                  %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\tokenize.py
> m traceback                 %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\traceback.py
> m types                     %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\types.py
> P unittest                  %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\unittest\__init__.py
> m unittest.case             %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\unittest\case.py
> m unittest.loader           %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\unittest\loader.py
> m unittest.main             %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\unittest\main.py
> m unittest.result           %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\unittest\result.py
> m unittest.runner           %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\unittest\runner.py
> m unittest.signals          %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\unittest\signals.py
> m unittest.suite            %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\unittest\suite.py
> m unittest.util             %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\unittest\util.py
> m warnings                  %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\warnings.py
> m weakref                   %PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\weakref.py
>
>  Missing modules:
> ? _emx_link imported from os
> ? ce imported from os
> ? fcntl imported from subprocess, tempfile
> ? org.python.core imported from copy, pickle
> ? os.path imported from os, shlex
> ? os2 imported from os
> ? posix imported from os
> ? pwd imported from posixpath
> ? readline imported from cmd, pdb
> ? riscos imported from os
> ? riscosenviron imported from os
> ? riscospath imported from os
> ```

As you can see, there is an awfully lot of modules (I modified the output a little bit, instead of the actual path I placed the *${PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR}* *env var* placeholder). In order for the *Python* code to work, you'll have to include all of those modules/packages in the installer.

**Notes** about *modulefinder*'s output (that I've noticed while playing with it):

- It searches for modules recursively, so here is the whole module dependency tree
- It searches for *import* statements located in functions (so, not only the ones at module level)
- It **doesn't** search for dynamic *import*s (e.g. [[Python 2.Docs]: __import__(name[, globals[, locals[, fromlist[, level]]]])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__))

So, looking at the modules that are required by *os*, I'm not sure that taking out the *site* import from *C*, makes much of a difference.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: To make sure your *.exe* works on any computer, you might consider including *VStudio C Runtime Library* or *VCRTLib* (***msvcr##(#).dll***: [[MS.Learn]: Run-Time Library Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/59ey50w6(v=vs.100))) (where *#*s are placeholders for digits - representing *VStudio* version) in your installer.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. Setting the Py_NoSiteFlag to 1 fixed the problem, and importing additional modules is straightforward! Thanks for your help.