# Possible to execute a Python script within a C++ process?

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

Is it possible to execute a Python script from a C++ thread, so that the Python runs from the C++ thread, rather than forking a new process?

I am aware of Boost Python, but that seems to only allow calling C++ from within Python?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39539089/what-files-are-required-for-py-initialize-to-run/39541474#39541474.

Comment: Boost.Python [works both ways](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/embedding.html)