# How to execute python from C++

Tags: python, c++

I have a C++ program that needs to make certain calls to a library which is written in Python.  (As opposed to rewriting the entire library in C++...)

What's the simplest way to do this?  I need to pass 2 numbers into the library, and get 2 numbers back.

I need it to be portable and run in both Windows and Linux, so for example using POSIX popen is not possible.

So far the best solution I have is to write a python wrapper, called by a "system" call in the C++ code, that takes command line parameters, calls the function, and writes the result to a file, which is then opened by the C++ program.

If you know anything better please let me know...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39539089/what-files-are-required-for-py-initialize-to-run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If boost is an option, you can use [boost.python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html) : [embedding](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/embedding.html)

Comment: The most relevant part of that doc is here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/embedding.html

Answer (score 1):

You can directly embed the python interpreter into your application. See [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html) for a full explanation.