# How to execute python code in C++ program

Tags: python, c++, windows

I'm trying to figure out how can I execute Python code in a C++ program. Where, The C++ program will be a static Executable which will run on systems where python is NOT installed. But it can execute Python code without Python having to be installed on the System it's running on.

I looked onto embedding the python interpreter within my Program. I found this link 
[Embedding Python in Another Application](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html). But the file `Python.h` is not found anywhere on my system (Python 3.7). I really need help on this. What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: why is c++ involved at all? Is it an option to just give an executable where everything is in pure python? (essentially, is this an XY problem?)

Comment: C++ is necessary due to project requirement. Also I do not trust python scripts that are converted to Executable.

Comment: Have a look at [Cython](https://cython.org/). Not exactly C++, as you say is a requirement, but is similar to what you describe.

Comment: You want to execute python code "where python is not installed". I don't think that's possible, you need a python interpreter somehow.

Comment: @BiagioFesta Well it is possible though. Just trying to figure out how.

Comment: If you can get the python libraries and headers, just cannot run the executable, then you could "execute python" by interacting with the Python C API directly.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/57961942/10933809