# What's the best way to make a private, self-contained python environment?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I want to create a private, self-contained Python environment that doesn't link back to system libraries (the way virtualenv does) and also includes its own versions of standard C/C++ libraries for Python packages that are simply wrappers for these libraries (PIL and libjpeg, for example).

I've seen commercial apps that distribute an entire runtime in a directory, so I know it can be done.

The question is, is there a tool that makes this easy to do? Virtualenv almost gets me there, esp. with the --no-site-packages and the --relocatable flags, but it doesn't solve the problem for standard "C" libraries. I want to be able to build a PIL, for example, that uses the bundled private version of libjpeg and libpng

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this for your own use or do you want to package it for distribution? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: For my own use. Ideally, I'd like a "portable environment" I can move from machine to machine of the same basic architecture and os

Answer (score 6):

It sound like what your really after is a way to bundle up a particular python installation and script into a distributable package.  You can do the following:

- Download, compile and install python into a project directory *(ie. python-toolchain)*
- Create a prefix script *(toolchain)* that will take a relative path and update `PATH`, `PYTHONPATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` dynamically.

```
#!/bin/sh

# If your clever you can determine install directory dynamically
prefix='install directory'
toolchain=$prefix/python-toolchain
export PATH=$toolchain/bin:$prefix/app/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$toolchain/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$prefix/app/lib:$PYTHONPATH
exec $*
```

- The magic cookie in your app script can then look like this:

```
#!.../install directory/toolchain python

print "Hello World!"
```

- You should now be able to distribute a directory like this:

  - `package/`

    - `python-toolchain/`
    - `app/`

Answer (score 1):

Try cx_Freeze or py2exe. They're used to package Python apps to make them redistributable, and include all the packages/libraries that it depends on.

Comment: I was looking more for a way to have a portable development environment I could install on every machine I used, not a frozen system for distribution. But maybe these packaging programs can be used to freeze a dev environment, too....

Comment: I see. In that case, you can just try using setuptools to create a source distribution, with install_requires defined so it will get all the dependencies you need from pypi. After that, creating a development environment on another machine would simply be just downloading the sources into that machine and running the setup script.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) successfully. There's also [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/).

See also here for more suggestions:

- [Are there any alternatives to py2exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689086/are-there-any-alternatives-to-py2exe)

Regarding this statement:

> that doesn't link back to system libraries

You of course can't completely eliminate that it requires some system libraries. If you want a Windows application it will have to use the Windows API for example. I assume you don't want to bundle an entire copy of Windows with your application just in case they don't have Windows installed....

Comment: Right. Things that are generally included with the OS. But special libraries used by a particular package