# Created an .exe with py2exe, but when I copy paste from "dist" folder to desktop, doesn't run properly

Tags: python, executable, py2exe

I'm still new to Python and py2exe.  I've created an executable from py2exe, but when I try to copy the single .executable from the "dist" folder it was created in, and paste it else where (let's say my desktop), When I open the executable after it's moved from the folder it opens quickly disappears (it's a console application).  The program has several input/output, so this should not be the case.  Its DOES function correctly if I leave it the original "dist" folder.

Is there something I'm missing?  What do I need to do if I just want to take the single file (.exe) and put it on a different machine (that doesn't have Python installed) and get it to run correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Run it with Command Prompt to see what the output of the window is. There's an error, but you don't know what it is.

Comment: I use `cx_freeze`, which seems to work better (for me) than `py2exe`. So if `py2exe` doesn't work, read this question to see some other alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689086/are-there-any-alternatives-to-py2exe.

Comment: Consider creating a [single-file executable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/113014/1497596).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the dist directory is there a set of .dll files needed to run the exe file.

Comment: I added msvcr90.dll and python27.dll to the desktop, and it worked.  Is there any other way around dragging those 2 dll's around with the .exe?

Comment: Add them to a path where windows will search for them.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, you need the .dll files to run the program. It works however if you leave the program in the dist folder (or create a copy of dist) and create a **shortcut**. You can move the shortcut wherever you like and it will work, since the file itself is still in the folder with the .dlls.

Answer (score 0):

Put your dist folder into the system search path, and it should work fine.
This happened to me also in times past.