# Do you have to have pygame installed to run pygame games?

Tags: python, pygame

Do you have to have pygame installed to run pygame games? I have programmed a game in pygame on my Raspberry Pi (using the Adafruit WebIDE), and I don't want to have to run it on the Pi itself, so I am planning to use it on my Windows 8 box, and I don't have pygame installed on the Windows box.

Comment: To anyone who voted to close this question as off topic: It's not an off topic question. It's about Pygame, a library for building and running games on Python. The question asks how they could *take the game they programmed* and turn it into an executable.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need Pygame installed to run a python script with a reference to Pygame on Windows.  You can always use [Py2Exe](http://www.py2exe.org) to change it into an EXE file, and then you won't need Pygame installed.

I would provide more directions on how exactly to do that here, but it seems to be largely a 'spray and pray' process.

Another Stack Overflow question has dealt with [alternatives to Py2Exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689086/are-there-any-alternatives-to-py2exe).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for a computer to run a program, it needs to have the modules included in the program. It's like saying that you want to solve a quadratic equation but numbers do not exist yet. Especially if you want to edit it on your computer, you would need to have Pygame installed.

Comment: Actually, as mentioned above, it is indeed possible to "compile" Python scripts into independent Windows executables. Please don't let my downvote discourage you. See it as a sign to do more research in the future before answering.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run a python program without python installed. However you could make the program an exe file by using a certain converter. Some converters are py2exe, pyinstaller, and cx_freeze. I personally recommend cx_freeze. If you use cx_freeze you must add the line `import pygame._view` to your source code due to a bug.

Comment: George Stocker already provided the same answer a week ago. The added info about the `cx_freeze` bug is worth adding as a comment, but not as a new answer.