# What is the best approach with compiling PySide application

Tags: python, qt, cross-compiling, pyside

I have lot of pain while compiling pyside code for Linux...much less for Windows, and my source is around 300kb. I would like to know what is the safest way to compile it.

1. Is it the best to compile Qt, PySide bindings, Python 2.7, and every import with separate process?

1.1. If I do it this way, is it easier to trace errors?

1. Does qt4-qmake have any reason to use it while compiling?
2. Is it better to rewrite code for PyQt instead of Pyside?
3. Are it depending about happy combination of some versions, for instance: ( Qt v4.8.2, pyside 1.0.1, python 2.7.3 ) ?

**EDIT:**
By compiling mean to convert Python scripts into executable Windows/Linux programs, as py2exe, cx_Freeze or PyInstaller do.

I appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: I don't understand your question: 
1.- Do you want to build PySide? -> Use the Nicola's answer (BTW, compiling it on linux is much more easy that on windows)
2.- Compile an app using Pyside? -> Well, that is python code, it doesn't compile...
3.- Using Python Code in a C++ app? -> http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html

Comment: Pythonist could understand me...please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689086/are-there-any-alternatives-to-py2exe

Comment: OH! Do you want to make a standalone executable?

Well, you don't need to compile nothing (at least, using cx_freeze). Just install cx_freeze (or py2exe, etc, etc), make a setup.py file, run it (the setup.py file), and be happy :)

However, the trace errors are a pain to see (in windows).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My only experience is with cx_freeze (using python 3.3). It works in Windows/Linux/OSX.
A simple example can be found here (with its documentation): http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html#distutils

Another example:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# dependencies
build_exe_options = {
    "packages": ["os", "sys", "glob", "simplejson", "re", "atexit", "PySide.QtCore", "PySide.QtGui", "PySide.QtXml"],
    "include_files": [("./example/Ui/MainWindow.ui", "Ui/MainWindow.ui"),
                      ("./example/Ui/ExampleWidget.ui", "Ui/ExampleWidget.ui"),
                      ("./example/Ui/TestDialog.ui", "Ui/TestDialog.ui"),
                      ("./example/Resources/style.qss", "Ui/style.qss")], # this isn't necessary after all
    "excludes": ["Tkinter", "Tkconstants", "tcl"],
    "build_exe": "build",
    "icon": "./example/Resources/Icons/monitor.ico"
}

executable = [
    Executable("./bin/Example.py",
               base="Win32GUI",
               targetName="Example.exe",
               targetDir="build",
               copyDependentFiles=True)
]

setup(
    name="Example",
    version="0.1",
    description="Example", # Using the word "test" makes the exe to invoke the UAC in win7. WTH?
    author="Me",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables=executable,
    requires=['PySide', 'cx_Freeze', 'simplejson']
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, link and example. That is pretty much that I need.

Answer (score -2):

Follow the instructions given on the [PySide page on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide#building-pyside-on-a-unix-system-ubuntu-12-04-lts).

Comment: But it's about compiling PySide, not app with Pyside!?

Comment: That's explained in the page I linked, given that there is no binary official distribution for Linux.

Comment: Well, the Windows compilation is the most important.

Comment: Are you trying to cross-compile to a different platform? Maybe embedded? Otherwise the PyPI page explains also how to build for Windows. Maybe you should reformulate your question.