# Portable PySide libraries?

Tags: python, pyside, portability

Is there any way to execute python with pyside on a computer that has only python installed?

I need to distribute a simple tool on a lot of computers and we can't install pyside everywhere.

Comment: Hi, You may find this package useful: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze . You can take a look here too: . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397994/what-is-the-best-approach-with-compiling-pyside-application . Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any portable pyside libraries? You need to have PySide installed also, but I can't do that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PySide is a set of bindings for Qt, which is a library written in C++. And it is not part of the Python core.

If you want a GUI that is portable and that can be used with a default Python installation, consider [`tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html).

Comment: Thanks!  Even if it's not part of python core, aren't there any portable libraries?

Comment: I think that tkinter is good solution in this case. Please take a look here for further infos http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/gui/ . Good luck

Comment: @darkgaze: Not that I know of.

Comment: :(  That's so sad. Thanks for the info!!