# Python 3.4 script challenge

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2exe, xlsxwriter

I am a non programmer with experience only in VBA. I took up the challenge to automate some daily tasks in my company, and chose Python 3.4 to do it (not sure if was the best option).

The scripts I need to do are rather simple. They just need to read values from .txt file, perform calculations, and write values in a .xls template.

I read some topics in stackoverflow and got concerned about these two topics:

1. Is there a feasible way to write data in excel (COM automation, Python 3 packages)?
2. Will I be able to compile Python 3.4 into an .exe file? Users can't install things in their Desktops.

I am able to do a script like this in VBA, but I need an executable file that can be used by everybody.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1689086/1816580 for 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following tools:

1. XlsWriter https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/
2. Or Use Py2Exe to convert to a python script to executable http://www.py2exe.org/

Or if your looking to use a '.csv' file, there are built in libraries for that, which are pretty straightforward

Comment: 1. XlsxWriter is for Excel 2007+ XLSX files. I need a way to write in an Excel 97-2003 file (*.xls).